# Is it correct to make a comparison in this format: "from as adjective/adverb as to as adjective/adverb as"

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering if it's correct to use too many propositions one after another. For example, in the following sentence:

> I've seen them all, **from** **as** back east **as** China **to** **as** out west **as** America.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing *grammatically* wrong with the "as"es in this sentence. If you decide it sounds unpleasant you could reword it in some extreme way.

The greater problem is that "as ___ as" only works with adjectives that can have degrees of intensity. You could say "as hot as," because you can talk about "more hot" or "less hot." But "back" and "out" don't work that way, especially in the phrases used here; you can't be "more back east" or "less out west."

You can use "far," though:

> I've seen them all, from as far back east as China to as far out west as America.

Note, you can also just drop "back" and "out," and talk about "as far east/west." "Back east" only works in certain context, when the people talking have a shared point of reference, and can refer to different places. I associate it mainly with the American West, especially of the nineteenth century, in which "back east" referred to the Atlantic seaboard. As settlers moved westward, the eastern states were "back," where they had come from (as a group, if not personally). Meanwhile, European immigrants to America—or Asian immigrants on America's Pacific coast—might think of "back" very differently.

You often have "up north" and "down south," though, regardless of frame of reference. Thus the Swedish band Våsen has a tune called "Way Down in Småland," Småland being a region in the south of Sweden, even though it is "up north" for much of the rest of the world!